# Expecting Type Errors with Unions & Intersections

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype, discriminated-union

I'm working with [the following type definitions inside of Flow's try tool](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAqATgIYB2AzgJYbVzlgC8YAytQLY4x4kU10GYAD5gAQmXIBjABbVyAcz5Va9RqIAycODnlLJAtQG502fG07deB1UJYBvVGDBm8ALjAByDDcHlPADROYOR4AB4YAPwelD56qAC+prgEEhSyesqGdhZcPFm2jABkYI7OAEaSsh5p0jIA2gC6YInJ5lo6mb5qzLlWBX5gJWVg8DoeHTitmCniVTK9IxhwMXGKQc4IMnjkq8TxSTPt2jiLwTCctB7kAK4c5XjELYc8GC4eAz0Owa4e3t0MQLBSrpGQeKCkGCUAjAYBgAA8AFowOF8FI6IoXLNHsQ4E9tsQ8K0gA) and I'm seeing slightly strange behaviour when using intersections nested inside unions.

```
type Transition = SimpleTransition | BranchingTransition | LoopingTransition;

type SimpleTransition = {
  type: 'transition',
  next?: string
}

type BranchingTransition = SimpleTransition & {
  branch: Branch[] 
}

type LoopingTransition = SimpleTransition & {
  loop: Loop
}

type Branch = {
  to: string,
  when: string
}

type Loop = {
  limit: number 
}
```

I was expecting to see a type error when I tried to create a `Transition` that contained a mismatched property for one of it's union types.

```
let t: Transition = {
  type: 'transition',
  branch: false // <- expecting type error (boolean != Branch[])
}
```

I was hoping that the inclusion of the `branch` property would cause the type checker to check this object against `BranchingTransition` (then find a type mismatch between `boolean` and `Branch[]`, but instead it seems to just count as a `SimpleTransition` with an extraneous property.

I wondered whether this was just because `SimpleTransition` was the first union type that it was able to unify with, but changing the order of the types in the union seems to have no effect.

Interestingly when I remove `SimpleTransition` from the union, it works just fine [(although the error message is somewhat confusing)](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAqATgIYB2AzgJYbVzlgC8YAQmeQMYAW15A5iQo06DMAB8wAGThwcfQRxH1yAbnTZ8YAMrUAtjhh4hVWiuZgA3qjBhNeAFxgA5BiVmGzgDQ2w5PAAeGAD8TpRuCqgAvhq4BOwUPAomymIsugZGKR6MAGRWvgBGHDxOCVzcANoAumDRsVoycsnuoozp+obGreb51rbwck5NOPWYcWwl3Bb9dnBhEQI+tgjceOQLxJEx442yODO+MPq0TuQArnqFeMR1O0YYdk7ZbYe29k6uPZ7LYMWJ3CcUFIMEoBGAwDAAB4ALRgQL4Th0AR2CY3YhwW5rYh4epAA). Is there a way to structure these types to prevent this problem from occurring?

Answer (score 1):

Flow behaves correctly since

```
({
  type: 'transition',
  branch: false
}: SimpleTransition)
```

You can narrow down your types using the `$Exact` type (Flow 0.32+)

```
type Transition = $Exact<SimpleTransition> | BranchingTransition | LoopingTransition;
```

or writing your own equivalent (Flow 0.31-)

```
type Strict<T> = $Shape<T> & T;
type Transition = Strict<SimpleTransition> | BranchingTransition | LoopingTransition;
```